# The issue caused by changing Python versions

Tags: 20.04, python

After installing Python 3.9 on Ubuntu 20.04, the default terminal does not open. However, when reverting back to Python 3.8, the terminal opens successfully.

If you have experienced or found a solution to this issue, please let me know.

Comment: You've not said what Ubuntu 20.04 LTS product you're using, however if it's a Desktop, python3 is a required tool for many Ubuntu tools, thus you should expect them to not work if you change the defaults (*and that includes the version of python3*).  You can have multiple python3 versions installed; but do **not** change the default version (esp. on Desktop systems).

Comment: That's just how it is. You shouldn't modify the system version of Python; that will break all sorts of system software. Use venvs made using different versions of Python for your personal stuff